# django 2.0 model, alias field

Tags: python, django, django-models

My higher level goal is to have a polymorphic association between models and I think I can solve it with a model with this signature:

```
class Relation(models.Model):
   left = ForeignKey(Entity)
   right = ForeignKey(Entity)

   class Meta:
     db_table = 'entities'
```

then I can extend Relation as proxy so I can be more clear on my intention of left and right field, for ex:

```
class Authorship(Relation)
   author = AliasField('left')
   content = AliasField('right')

   class Meta:
      proxy = True
```

So then we can do the following:
`Authorship.objects.filter(author=user_entity)`
or 
`Authorship.objects.create(author=user_entity)`

My question is, how do I implement AliasField function described above?
I have looked at:

https://shezadkhan.com/aliasing-fields-in-django/

[How to create an alias for Django Model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985466/how-to-create-an-alias-for-django-model-field)

for the first link, I am getting error about name is not a field or something
for the second one, I am getting an error saying "can't adapt type"

is this even possible to do in Django 2.0?
I prefer not to use django-polymorphic

Thank you!