# Django : creating a field having the value of the (django-generated ) primary key of the same model

Tags: django, model, field

I'm trying to create an integer field (topic_id) equal to the Django-generated primary key value (id).

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    topic_id = ?????
```

Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it as a method and use @property decorator to return it as an actual property.

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    @property
    def topic_id(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: I don't want to turn topic_id into a primary key, I just want topic_id to retrieve the value of id

Comment: In the program I wrote, I need 'topic_id' to be a variable of the model Topic. If It's impossible to do it, I'll re-write my program to fit your solution. Thx bro.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `topic_id` an alias to `id` with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985466/how-to-create-an-alias-for-django-model-field):

```
class AliasField(models.Field):
    def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, private_only=False):
        super(AliasField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, private_only=True)
        setattr(cls, name, self)

    def __get__(self, instance, instance_type=None):
        return getattr(instance, self.db_column)

class Topic(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    topic_id = AliasField(db_column='id')
```

Comment: AttributeError : module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'AliasField'

Comment: My bad. I've updated my answer with the definition for `AliasField`.

Comment: Try it 4 times in different app, stil getting : "AttributeError : module 'django.db.models" has no attribute 'AliasField' (I'm on django2.1 FYI)

Comment: Fixed now. `AliasField` does not belong to the `models` package.

Comment: No more errors, but to variable 'topic_id' appears nowhere in the model. The structure of Topic model is still (id, text, date_added).

Comment: The structure will remain unchanged, but by creating an alias, you will be able to access the `id` field with `topic_id` instead, such that if you have an instance of `Topic` named `t`, you can use `t.topic_id` instead of `t.id` where needed.

Comment: Got it, Thx bro.

Answer (score 0):

Make your topic_id intergerfield

In def save():

```
self.topic_id = self.id
```

Comment: I'm a complete django rookie, could you please more specific...thx