# How to use ColllectionField()?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create model object to store multiple phone number. I am using CollectionField but getting error

```
  File "/home/shiv/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/collectionfield/models/fields.py", line 226, in contribute_to_class
    cls, name, virtual_only=virtual_only
TypeError: contribute_to_class() got an unexpected keyword argument 'virtual_only'
```

here is my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from django.utils import timezone
from collectionfield.models import CollectionField


class Applications(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=
    state = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    zone = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=zone_choice, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    phone_number = CollectionField()
    email_id = models.EmailField()
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

Comment: The error you're getting is because of incompatibility with Django 2.0 and higher where the [virtual_only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0) argument to `Field.contribute_to_class()` was removed. django-collection-field hasn't been updated since 2016 - doesn't look like it is maintained.

Comment: what should I do for django 1.8 If I want to store multiple value?

Answer (score 0):

virtual_only was depreciated in Django 2.0 in favour of private_only. 
See if replacing virtual_only=virtual_only with private_only=True in fields.py helps. The following reference could help as well:
[How to create an alias for Django Model field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985466/how-to-create-an-alias-for-django-model-field)